# QFT, more a QM Question, Hamiltonian relation time evolution

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

Question attached here:

[image]

I am just stuck on the first bit. I have done the second bit and that is fine. This is a quantum field theory course question but from what I can see this is a question solely based on QM knowledge, which I've probably forgot some of.

2. Relevant equations

I believe the only relevant equation to use is:

$\hat{H}\psi = i\frac{h}{2\pi}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} $

3. The attempt at a solution

First of all I thought I should log the expression to get, obviously I need to be careful to keep order:

$\hat{H}\hat{a(k)} = \hat{a(k)} (\hat{H}-\omega_k) $

I'm a bit thrown of by the fact that the Schrodinger equation acts on a state, the ladder operator itself isn't a state until acting upon a vacuum,, so perhaps if I included this it would make the algebra a bit easier as a 'test state' sort of thing with the operators, but I have omitted it for now).

I then conclude for the left hand side from the Schrodinger equation I get:

$ i\frac{h}{2\pi} \frac{\partial(\hat{H}\hat{a(k)}}{\partial t} = \hat{a(k)} (\hat{H}-\omega_k) $

$\hat{a(k)}$ does not depend on time, $w_k$ does, and so I have a first order linear differential equation, and could identify an integrating factor, however I don't think this approach is valid since my integrating involves the exponential of $\hat{a(k)}$ and order matters, also when working backward with the product rule of differentiation there is no order on $\frac{d}{dt}(uv)=vdu/dt+udv/dt $ and so if i turn u or v to operators, i dont think this integrating factor method will work?

I'm unsure what to do next/ how to approach if I am totally off. Other ideas I had where to
1) drop the 'test state' in the Schrodinger equation and raise the operators to the power of n, but this seems unnecessary when you can just log
2) take the conjugate of the Schrodinger equation, still treating $\hat{a(k)}$ as the 'test state' as said before, in order that I can plug something into the right hand side, once expanded, which ofc has opposite order of the operators to the lhs : $\hat{a(k)}\hat{H}$ instead.

Many thanks

Comment: The first equation in (3.) is usually written as a commutation relation. It makes sense as an operator equation - you don't need to think about it acting on the vacuum. The "$a$"s are operators, not states. Why to you say $w_k$ depends on time?

Comment: thanks keith. any replies to how to address the question?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to derive the first equation? Can't you just do $H^2a =Ha(H-w)= a (H-w)^2$, etc.

Comment: no the seconnd equation. it says under that one you are not asked to derive this

Comment: also what have you used for this, I'm guessing the commutator of $H$ and $a$ which we are not given in the question, nor given the expression for H in terms of a and so can not use the commutator of the a's to get it

Comment: If this is a non-rigorous course you can formally expand the exponentials. Since $w$ is a constant (commutes with $H$) the product formula works the same as for two constants.